# how to change map in map_server?

Tags: navigation, mapping, rosbridge, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

now  if i want to change a map , i need kill the map_server node now running,  then start it again with other map name.

is there another way to change map without restart the node?

so thankyou if anything help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270129/how-to-change-map-in-map_server?/) by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-09-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I explored this same question a while ago, see https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/279

As you point out, to load a new map with the current *map_server* implementation, you need to kill the node and reload it.

A possible solution, that doesn't require any changes in *map_server*  (as proposed by @david-lu), would be to load all your different maps in separate *map_server* instances renaming appropriately the */map* topic on each instance (for example /map_1, /map_2, etc...) and use a [multiplexer](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux) that subscribes to all your maps and publishes the topic */map* depending on which map you want the multiplexer to select.

The other solution would be to modify the source code of  *map_server* and add a service to change the map on demand. Some work has been done, but it hasn't been released yet. If you read through [navigation issue #279](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/279) you will find the code.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) on 2017-09-04**:
thankyou so much , i will try the [topic_tools/mux](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux), then paste the result.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-04**:
This is a good solution. I like the idea of multiplexing the map topic for different maps.

**Comment by [uffe](https://answers.ros.org/users/38684/uffe/) on 2018-11-24**:
@marine0131 did you go for this option, how did you fare? can you share your solution

**Comment by [EFernandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/13791/efernandes/) on 2019-02-13**:
Anyone tried this approach?

I've tried it, but although the map server is latched, when I select the topic with the mux there is no map. Only when I restart the map server...

Any thoughts on this?
Thank you

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-02-27**:
You are right, the map server is latched, but since the multiplexer subscribes only once to each topic (when you launch the multiplexer) the map will not be resent through the multiplexer when you select the topic you want to listen to.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-02-27**:
Anyway, there seems to be progress on this, check out this PR: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/461

**Comment by [jpmf](https://answers.ros.org/users/142468/jpmf/) on 2023-03-20**:
I have the same problem. Has anyone been able to implement this solution? I tried following several suggestions and none worked for me.